# Импорт в python на iOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, ios, iphone, импорт

Хочу заставить iphone 5s нормально работать с python но сегодня столкнулся с неприятной проблемой:
Скрипт **INIT** пытается импортировать скрипт six но не находит его, почему?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

import six  ---> from . import six